# Using NHibernate for DotNetNuke Modules?

Tags: nhibernate, dotnetnuke

I'm thinking of adopting a more Domain-Driven-Design approach to DotNetNuke module development and would like to consider using NHibernate as an OR/M layer.

Does anyone have experience using NHibernate with DotNetNuke?  I've used SubSonic and EntitySpaces, but not NH.

**UPDATE**
Sorry, I should have been more clear.  Is NHibernate capable of running in Medium Trust and able to run in the context of the DotNetNuke "objectqualifier" ?  The DNN object qualifier is essentially a prefix that can be applied to all database table names.  So on my DNN install I might have a table named "Products", but on someone else's the same table might be named "dnn_Products" where the "dnn" is the "objectqualifier".  So essentially NHibernate would need to read the objectqualifier from the web.config at runtime and apply it.

Comment: @paco how to use NHibernate for accessing data from database

Comment: I have done used NHiberante with DotNetNuke but there is no direct relation between Dotnetnuke and NHiberante, so I cannot tell anything Dnn specific related to NHibernate. The question asked by user422176 can only be answered by true or false.

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate can be used with essentially any table name.  When you define the table mapping in your mapping xml you need to simply define the table name as dnn_Products.  As long as that is the actual name of the table then it will work.  NHibernate is capable of running in Medium Trust, the trick is getting the NHibernate dll's into your DNN install.  You can add them in an [Assembly Component](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/Page/AssemblyComponent) from what I understand but I have never had the need to validate that personally.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this [example](http://blogs.rawsoft.nl/remco/post/2009/02/13/DotNetNukeMVP-Model-View-Presenter-framework-for-DotNetNuke-%28part-1%29.aspx).

The article is not for the same topic you are looking but it will give you good idea about it.